# Event didn't apppear in pusher after sent by Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, pusher

I'am trying to register event, but nothing appear in pusher console. Any suggestion whats wrong with my code?

```
var Pusher = require('pusher');

channels_client = new Pusher({
  app_id: 'my own',
  key: 'my own',
  secret: 'my own',
  cluster: 'eu'

});

channels_client.trigger('my-channel', 'my-event', {
  message: 'hello world'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the property app_id, this needs to be appId. Your code should be as follows:

```
var Pusher = require('pusher');

channels_client = new Pusher({
  appId: 'my own',
  key: 'my own',
  secret: 'my own',
  cluster: 'eu'

});

channels_client.trigger('my-channel', 'my-event', {
  message: 'hello world'
})
```

I hope that helps!